# Magento select products filter

Tags: magento

Hi I have a script that selects products. But it select all products, which have manufacturer 3,5. It works fine but I wanna select products that haven't fill in a field manufacturer. How can I do this?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array(3,5))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you exactly want. Please elaborate what you mean by `I wanna select products that haven't fill in a field manufacturer`

Comment: On my website I have 2000 products, but only 1800 have fill manufacturer, but I want select products which havent fill manufacturer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'manufacturer',
                'null' => 'null' //this value don't matter
            )    
         )
     )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: @PatrikvanDendis Glad! Please accept the answer if it helped you solve.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `null` operator:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 'null')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Or the `equals` operator:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => ''))
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```